# emailing scripts

Tags: bash

Trying to send mail with the following script, I substitute $1 with the email address I want to send the email to.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to send simple email
# email subject
SUBJECT="SET-EMAIL-SUBJECT"
# Email To ?
EMAIL="$1"
# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
echo "This is an email message test"> $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "This is email text" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
# send an email using /bin/mail
mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

I have tried sending myself emails with this script, but I don't get anything. I also don't get an error which makes it more difficult to figure out what's wrong. Anyone know how to send an email through a script? 
I'm on a macbook pro, and my operating system is Leopard.

Ted.

Comment: Shouldn't the body be appended by `\n.\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(worth a shot to try another method)

```
cat $EMAILMESSAGE | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"
```

---

But other reasons you aren't getting the email could possibly be that, whomever /bin/mail is passing the email off to is never making it to the server.  See if you have the **mailq** command ?

Also, sometimes email's generated like this look really raw without a lot of headers and often get tossed into the **spam** folder.

Comment: Is this any different from doing the ` < $EMAILMESSAGE` ?

Comment: lol not really, but when one method doesn't work, you try another!  Sometimes things that should work, don't, and things that shouldn't work, do!

Comment: I tried the mailq command as you said but I get this error:
postqueue: fatal: Queue report unavailable - mail system is down